# Route 'Home' should declare a screen--react native issue

Tags: react-native, npm

I'm new to React Native and trying to flesh out a basic front end. I have an existing Node server which performs CRUD operations--right now I am trying to flesh out a home/landing page and the signup page which can be accessed from there. Thanks!

I've seen this issue raised in other posts and it seems to usually be a matter of defining this StackNavigator after a class, but that isn't what I did. Any help would be much appreciated.

```html
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import {t} from 'tcomb-form-native';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Button
} from 'react-native';

const App = StackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: Home},
    Signup: { screen: Signup},
});

var user =  t.struct({
   name: t.String,
   username: t.String,
   password: t.String,
   email: t.String
});
var options = {};

export default class Home extends Component {
  _signup(){
    //goes to the signup screen
    navigate('Signup')

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        //this should move to a new screen which will render the signup form!
        <Button style={styles.instructions}>
          onPress={this._signup()}
          title="sign up"
          color="#841584"
          accessibilityLabel="Sign up for my app"
        </Button>
        <Button style = {styles.instructions}>
          onPress={}
          title="view offers"
          color="#841584"
          accessibilityLabel="View offers on my app"
        </Button>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,
          Shake or press menu button for dev menu
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class Signup extends Component {
  onPress(){
      var value = this.refs.form.getValue();
      console.log(value);
      //todo: wire up fetch to perform verification on node server
  }

  render() {
    return(
   <View style={styles.container}>
   <Form
   ref="form" type={user} options={options}/>
   <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={this.onPress} underlayColor={'#99d9f4'}>
     <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Submit</Text>
   </TouchableHighlight>
   </View>
    )};
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
      button: {
      height: 36,
      backgroundColor: '#48BBEC',
      borderColor: '#48BBEC',
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderRadius: 8,
      marginBottom: 10,
      alignSelf: 'stretch',
      justifyContent: 'center'
  },
    buttonText: {
        fontSize: 18,
        color: 'white',
        alignSelf: 'center'
    },

});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Home', () => Home);
AppRegistry.registerComponent('Signup', () => Signup);
```

Comment: All this code is in single file ?

Comment: You should make several files, one for each Component and one for the Navigator. In the files of the Component you can export default these Components and then import them in the Navigator file.

Comment: Paras Watts: Yes, all of this code is in a single file.  Didn't think it would matter.

Comment: kolbma: Ok, I'll try separating them out now